# How to prevent user from becoming superuser

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin, root

I have some managers in my project, they are "staff", so have access to admin panel.
Also, they can add and change users.

So, I want to prevent them from changing their profile to "superuser". I also would like to hide the "Permissions" section in the User Editing Form from manager.

I thought, that `auth|permission|can change\add\delete permission` is managing this, but my managers doesnt have such permission, and still have "Permissions" section in the user editing form.

Comment: Sorry everybody, failed, none expierenced)

But question then: how to prevent change passwords buy getting url:
admin/auth/user/%some_number%/password/?